# The registry key for Windows Kit (SDK) 10.0

Tags: visual-studio, registry

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Ed. And now there are registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8***
```

for each SDK v8.* But there is not such a key for SDK v10.0.

So I wonder, have anyone, who installed VS 2015, the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0`?

Or just I have a broken installation?